# Link to Algorithmic behind signatures verification

Tags: signature, validation

Does anyone know a good paper where the process of signature verification is explained (message+signature+public key = valid/not_valid) ??? And I mean it at a low level, with the code or pseudo-code of the algorithms doing the verification or similar. All sources I have found explain it with the verification process being pretty much a black box.

I know StackExchange is not the place to ask for references, but I haven't found what I am looking for, so someone might now a good source...

Thank you all in advance. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Signature generation:

```
xRandSignPoint, yRandSignPoint = EccMultiply(Gx,Gy,RandNum)
R = xRandSignPoint % N
S = ((HashOfThingToSign + R * privKey) * (modinv(RandNum,N))) % N
```

Signature verification:

```
w = modinv(S,N)
xu1, yu1 = EccMultiply(Gx,Gy,(HashOfThingToSign * w)%N)
xu2, yu2 = EccMultiply(xPublicKey,yPublicKey,(R * w)%N)
X,Y = ECadd(xu1,yu1,xu2,yu2)
if R == X:
    print "Signature verified"
```

`EccMultiply` – elliptic curve point on scalar multiplication.

`ECadd` – elliptic curve 2 points addition.

Here is the original [source](https://github.com/wobine/blackboard101/blob/master/EllipticCurvesPart5-TheMagic-SigningAndVerifying.py).